# How to avoid eslint indent errors if you break function call into 2 lines

Tags: node.js, eslint

i still want to have the eslint indent check on for most of the time, but for this case i don't want to turn it off line by line, too much typing for each line.

```
const ret = myfunc(v1, v2,
                   v3, v4);
```

you can see v3 supposed to be align with v1.

Comment: Did you look at the options for that rule?

Answer (score 0):

As jonrsharpe suggested, i went to https://eslint.org/docs/rules/indent and found plenty of options, not covering all my cases, but it's a good starting point.
Thanks jonrsharpe !